# How to get the image path when selecting image from the database in laravel? This helps us to display image without using helper function "asset()"

Tags: laravel

[this is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGMSG.png)[there is a property name (image), I want image path to be shown there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XL4Xp.png)[I want to get the image path in the newImage variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XL4Xp.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XL4Xp.png): I have tried to store image path along with image name in the database but it does not meet the client requirements. Is there any ways to get the image path other than this?

Comment: What is not working with this approach, what is the requirement? Please add your code aswell as more details, otherwise it is unlikely for someone to answer your question.

Comment: Please help me. I am junior level developer. is there a way to get image path ?

Comment: You can user accessor https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators where you will set image path using laravel path helpers https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#paths

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.